# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, automated-tests

Getting the following error when running rspec tests

> > unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) in rails

Using latest ruby (1.9.2) and firefox (6.0)

Using rspec-rails, capybara and several other gems, but they don't seem to be a problem. These tests run fine in another environment (linux).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[Update - this can (was for me) still be a fix for this issue in **2015** |mdurrant|]

I came across [this problem lately](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/460).

You should upgrade to capybara v1.0.1 to have a correct selenium webdriver.

To be sure I added:

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.25.0'
```

in my Gemfile.

**Important note**:
The `selenium-webdriver` gem is updated, and a new version released, for every subsequent version of Firefox. Presently, version **`2.25.0`** is needed to support **Firefox 15**.

Comment: I actually did 'bundle update selenium-webdriver', but either way the goal is to update selenium-webdriver gem to 2.5.0. The tests ran fine after the update.

Comment: just did. sorry for the delay.

Comment: had to do - gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 2.5.0' - for firefox 11. this got me gem version 2.10...

Comment: And selenium-webdriver 2.31.0 is needed for Firefox 19. Seems like the answer is always, "get the latest selenium-webdriver."

Comment: I always just leave the version number off of `selenium-webdriver` and do `bundle update selenium-webdriver` when the version needs updating.

Answer (score 17):

I couldn't get it to work with Firefox 10 on Ubuntu. Switching to Chrome helped.

Install [Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver).

spec_helper.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|   
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

In your spec:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
... tests ...
Capybara.use_default_driver
```

Comment: if you're on a mac you can simply `brew install chromedriver`

Comment: Worked for me, except  did like so: ```Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome``` (instead of setting ```current_driver```.)

Comment: Switching to Chrome helped you establish a stable Firefox connection?  Fascinating. :)

Answer (score 12):

For anybody experiencing this with Firefox 12, the current selenium webdriver (2.21) doesn't support FF12.  The only solution I have found is to continue using Firefox is to downgrade Firefox, until selenium-webdriver is updated with FF12 support.

This can be done using synaptic package manager by selecting the Firefox package, and clicking  Package menu > Force Version > select an earlier version.  Then apply changes.

If you don't have synaptic, you can install it with apt-get install synaptic.

**Update: Firefox 12 support was added in 2.22 and FF13 support was added in 2.23**

Comment: selenium-webdriver Works with FF12 for me with 2.22.0.rc1

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this error because the specs were being run on a headless server.  This meant there was no display for the browser to render onto.

[This article](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/capybara/capybara_with_selenium_and_webkit.html) suggests using a virtual X server ([X Virtual Framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)).  This allows the browser to render in a virtual display.

Install like so:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo apt-get install x11-xkb-utils
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
```

Then run the specs with the command `xvfb-run` in front.

```
xvfb-run bundle exec rake spec:features
```

[This was the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863974/848668) that lead me to the above article.  It also gives an alternative means to use Xvfb.

Comment: its "xfonts-cyrillic", last c was missing

Answer (score 3):

> */var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in
>   `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in
>   60 seconds
>   (127.0.0.1:7055)(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)*

I had the same problem, updating the `selenium-webdriver` did not help (it was the most current version available already).

It turns out, that I tried to run my script from an SSH session, and `$DISPLAY` was not set.

The problem was fixed with:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

before starting my Ruby script from the SSH session (use `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal on the X session to find out what you need to put into this variable).

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle update selenium-webdriver
```

Comment: Plus 1, In 2015 this was the easiest fix for me.  No messing with hard coding versions numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 'launchy' gem to my application's Gemfile worked with FF13.0, Capybara & Selenium v1.8.24.

Comment: I suspect that if this fixed the issue, it would only be because adding launchy caused a later version of capybara to be pulled in (e.g. as a dependency).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a reiteration of what everyone was saying above.  I checked my gemfile and made sure that the 'selenium-webdriver' didn't have any limits on it then ran a 'bundle update' and it worked.

I'm on ubuntux64 and windows 8 x64