# "unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds" using latest selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to test a javascript-enabled Rails page using Capybara and shoulda. My setup is Ubuntu 11.10 (and FireFox 7) running on VirtualBox with Windows 7 as host. I have therubyracer in my gems.

My test code looks like this:

```
context "with javascript" do
  setup do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
  end

  should "handle javascript" do      
    visit '/'
    click_link 'Hi'
    assert page.has_content? "Hello"
  end
end
```

(where the link with text "Hi" has a simple jQuery click() function to write "Hello" into another div; it works live) but the test reports:

```
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
Exception `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError' at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.9.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:77:in `connect_until_stable'
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263564/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055), but I've now `bundle update`d both capybara and selenium-webdriver (the latter to 2.9.1) and I still get the same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: This worked for me just now. Whether it's because I got lucky and the timeout didn't occur, or whether it's because I had FF already running, I don't know.

Comment: it worked for me after i switched to FF 9.0

Answer (score 31):

Upgrading selenium-webdriver worked for me:

```
bundle update selenium-webdriver
```