# Can not use variable in IRB after var = Watir::Browser.start 'url'

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, irb

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true 
1.9.3-p327 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new
```

Then firefox starts and I can do nothing. My IRB does not allow me to enter new commands.

Tried different variations of browser initialization:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :opera
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b = Watir::Browser.start 'url'
```

There should appear something like:

```
=> #<OperaWatir::Browser:0x1496e57 @active_window=#<OperaWatir::Window:0x1eb1db2
@browser=#<OperaWatir::Browser:0x1496e57 ...>>,@driver=#
Java::ComOperaCoreSystems::OperaDriver:0xeabd2f>>
```

but there is no output in console. After 60 seconds browser closes and I get the following output:

```
1.9.3-p327 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection
in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
```

Tried chrome, firefox, browser opens, but irb locks.

OS:Ubuntu

Ruby: 2.0.0 (also tried on 1.9.3)

Answer (score 5):

***`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError unable to obtain stable firefox connection
in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)`*** - this happened generally when your browser version and `web-driver` version not matched. I personally observed the same. Only solution is to synchronize `watir-webdriver` and your browser version as documented in their official site.

Here are some Good resources of the fact:

[`resource1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303161/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

[`resource2`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/watir-general/YdJ4x4eF_qg)

[`resource3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263564/unable-to-obtain-stable-firefox-connection-in-60-seconds-127-0-0-17055)

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thank you, after updating selenium-webdriver everything went good.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden no given link answer is by me- how good is it? just to evaluate - :)

Comment: @RubyLovely as I promised ;)