# watir hang up after new browser

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir

I just installed watir, after exec

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

it just open the browser but keep hang up. Can now write anything more at IRB console beacuse the "browser =" operation do not finish. I'm using firefox 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `gem update selenium-webdriver`

similar question here
[Can not use variable in IRB after var = Watir::Browser.start 'url'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036096/1859408)

Comment: oh! I'm already google that, the gem is just intalled in the latest version

Comment: Nop. As I told, is a recen installed version of watir, it is fresh. Then, I run update and tell that there is nothing to update

Answer (score 1):

Having run into this problem once every year or so, I've basically come to the conclusion that this has to do with a misalignment of three different pieces of software that have to work together: Firefox, the selenium-webdriver and geckodriver. The easy fix for any permutation of this issue should be to:

- update firefox
- Update selenium/watir -- `bundle update selenium-webdriver` or `gem update selenium-webdriver`
- Update geckodriver -- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases,  swap previous "geckodriver" file out with new one

Other error messages that the above described misalignment can cause:

- `EOFError: end of file reached`
- `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: no sessionId in returned payload`

Comment: this is not rails, selenium-webdriver is just installed and there is nothing to update. Selenium is not working, perphaps firefox's recents version are not working with selenium

Comment: does your ruby application cache its apps? try updating &/or replacing them.

Comment: I JUST INSTALLED, gem update selenium do not work, I do a fresh installation and the problem persist. **Just installed Ruby with just installed selenium.**

Comment: I uninstalled all of the watir & selenium related gems (all versions) first before I did this

Answer (score 0):

solved, after update **FIREFOX** to newer version